Openiddict - Client App loosing authorization when opening a second Client App
I've developed an Identity Server using Openiddict & AspNetCore Identity to handle the SSO for some internal Client Applications.
I'm facing a weird situation when running at least 2 Client Apps at the same time. Here's the flow:

Launching Identity Server [Ok]
Launching ClientApp1 and perform the Login [Ok]
Launching ClientApp2, the Login is already done from Step2 [Ok]
Performing ClientApp1 Ajax request to an Authorized Controller/Action => throws js 401 (Unauthorized) [Not Ok]
Refreshing page for ClientApp1 and remake the request => request successful [Ok]
Performing ClientApp2 Ajax request to an Authorized Controller/Action => throws js 401 (Unauthorized) [Not Ok]
Refreshing page for ClientApp2 and remake the request => request successful [Ok]
In this moment, the authorization is lost for ClientApp1. Go back to Step 4 and so on...

During this flow, it never redirects to Login (it doesn't have to, and it's ok) but the ClientApp requires a page refresh to obtain the authorization.
I isolated the case using Openiddict samples and could replicate the situation. Here are the samples provided by Openiddict: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Velusia
I cloned Velusia.Client to have 2 Clients Apps and then run all of them.
Cookie Authentication Schema is added like this for both Client Apps:
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})

.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
    options.SlidingExpiration = false;
});


Developer Tools Cookies
I've tried to give a different name for Cookies for each Client Application and force the handler to re-issue a new cookie like this:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.Name = ".Client1";
});

and
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.Name = ".Client2";
});

Now, everything seems to be fine, the authorization is no longer lost but on logout from ClientApp1 doesn't logout the user from ClientApp2 and it's because the Identity Server cannot clear the cookies for ClientApp2.
Developer Tools Cookies
Any idea would be gratefully appreciated!
Thank you!

the initial problem seems like it would be expected behavior for anti-forgery tokens.  Were those ajax calls expecting anti-forgery?  Are these 2 "client apps" on the same domain/server?  If so, there's no reason your logout couldn't write two cookies with expiry in the past.  (client1 and client2)  Refresh token might be another story if auth server is not same server as resource server.

Thanks for the comment. Yes, the 2 client apps are on the same domain, and Identity Server is on the same server as Resource Server.
As a workaround I had to set cookies as HttpOnly = false and force clearing them on logout (on javascript side). It's not what I wanted and also it's not secure but it's all I can do for now.

I think the backend could still send cookies with expiry in the past.  (add to the headers and it should be first response)  You won't have to change httponly flag.

I mean, if Identity Server cannot invalidate cookies for the other Client Apps (except the current one which performs the Logout), I have to manually clear them by set an expiration date in the past, on javascript side. If HttpOnly flag is True, there's no way to access cookies, they're not visible.

You can't set cookies from server?  (http header)
